# Netbeans 8.0.2 organize imports, possible bug?

Tags: java, netbeans, import

I'm working in Netbeans 8.0.2 under Mac OS and I have a problem in my *Organize imports* configuration. An image tells more than a thousand words, here is my configuration:

[image: imports configuration]

And in a class I have the following:

[image: class imports]

Just to clarify I put the package of the file in the image, classes from `ar.edu.unt.sigea.` are classes from my application. As you can see, in the automatic import I get a duplicated line (the last static import and the yellow underlined, this last one being recognized as unused import by Netbeans). If I delete manually the last static import (repeated) and save the file, Netbeans put the repeated line again.

Am I missing something in the configuration or it's an unresolved bug in Netbeans? Thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: Well, since one shouldn't use wildcard imports anyway, use this as a suitable chance to remove them from your code :).

Comment: Jaja, I'll take it into account. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a bug of Netbeans:
[254955: static imports of methods are being duplicated without reason](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254955).

It is not yet fixed in a stable version of Netbeans, but you can apply a patched attached to the [bug](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=254955#c16).

Comment: Thank you, I gave up some time ago with this post. Hope they fix it up in later versions.